# How to add versioning for JSON files using gulp etc?

Tags: javascript, json, gulp, versioning

I have a hybrid app which needs constant modification. So I need a versioning system, for all of my files.

Using [Gulp-rev-append](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rev-append) I can have a versioning for my Javascript, CSS files in index.html but how can I have a versioning for my JSON file as that is also changed but it is only downloaded according to the need in the app.

Edit : I need versioning because the files are there in device local cache also and the versioning provides a mechanism for the device to know that the file has been changed and fetch the new file instead of taking from the local.

All of my files are being accessed from S3 bucket. The JSON files are accessed using XHR request.`$http.get(jsonURL)`

For JS, CSS we can have the url defined in the index.html as :

`<script src="app/index.run.js?rev=5456654"></script>` .

But how can we do the same for JSON file?

EDIT 2 : For now I will manually edit the JSON in the http request in my JS file, till I find a gulp plugin for that.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @DomeTune How can I add versioning in my JSON file. Should I explain a little more anywhere?

Comment: Haven't got experience with Gulp, but did you try adding a datetime variable to the end of file names? e.g.: superscript.js?2017-02-27-12-27 (current datetime UTC) If you use these names in your HTML, and the file is updated, the parameter won't match the cached file and will be re-requested...

Comment: Yes, please explain, where your problem is, and what you cannot achieve yet.

Comment: @Nukeface That is how we do for JS, CSS file. But how to do that for JSON file as that is accessed through an HTTP request.

Comment: @arqam — You're asking how to change the URL that is being requested, but we can't tell you that because we don't know how it is being requested.

Comment: @Quentin : All of my files are being accessed from S3 bucket. The JSON files are accessed using XHR request.$http.get(jsonURL)

Comment: Couldn't you modify the same principle as you use for JS/CSS, but then within the JSON files' data? E.g. a response: `{name: "henk donutmuncher", age: 22, occupation: {...}, lastUpdated: "2017-03-02 23:30:00"}`. Then also save the `lastUpdated: "timestamp"` into that local storage, but include it in the new request? If then the timestamps don't match, the new response you'll get will have a different timestamp, thus new data.